# bash arrays created by sourcing inside a function have local scope but scalars are global

Tags: arrays, bash, macos, function, scope

Consider the following bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env /bin/bash

function sourcefile(){
  source /tmp/srcfile
  echo "Sourced array in func: ${sourcedarray[*]}"
  echo "Sourced scalar in func: ${sourcedscalar}"
}

globalarray=([0]="xyzzy" [1]="kaboom")
globalscalar="argle"

cat >/tmp/srcfile <<EOF
export sourcedscalar="bargle"
export sourcedarray=([0]="foo" [1]="bar")
EOF

sourcefile

echo "Global array: ${globalarray[*]}"
echo "Global scalar: ${globalscalar}"
echo "Sourced array: ${sourcedarray[*]}"
echo "Sourced scalar: ${sourcedscalar}"
```

One would reasonably expect all four values to be set in the output, but at least with bash version `3.2.57(1)-release` (yes, yes I know: we all pay for Apple's paranoia) that is not the case:

```
Sourced array in func: foo bar
Sourced scalar in func: bargle
Global array: xyzzy kaboom
Global scalar: argle
Sourced array:
Sourced scalar: bargle
```

As far as I can tell:

- a scalar variable created in a function by sourcing a file is created in global scope
- but an array variable created in a function by sourcing a file is created in *local* scope, and exporting it does not change this

This seems inconsistent to put it mildly: is there some way to work around this behavior?

Comment: I can confirm it works correctly (all values displayed) in bash 4.4.23 on Linux.

Comment: I can confirm OPs problem in [bash 4.3.11](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_bash_shell). In 5.1.4 it doesn't work any longer, just like choroba pointed out. Therefore, there must have been some change between somewhere between 4.3 and 4.4.

Comment: Interesting. A few more tests: 

`5.1.4(1)-release` from homebrew on macos: works correctly (all values displayed)
`5.0.3(1)-release` on debian buster: works correctly
`4.4.20(1)-release` on ubuntu bionic: works correctly
`4.3.48(1)-release` on ubuntu xenial: broken (sourced array is empty)

Comment: Apple's paranoia -- check!  Me paying for it -- not ever.

Comment: I tried assigning to `sourcedarray` before sourcing the file, and that appeared to create a global array that was independent of the "local" assignment in the sourced file. Furthermore, adding `declare -p sourcedarray` in the function prints it as `declare -ax  ...` where the `x` should indicate it really is exported?!?

Comment: Bye the way: `#!/usr/bin/env /bin/bash` is combining only the drawbacks of `#!/bin/bash` (hardcoded semi-standard path) and `#!/usr/bin/env ...` (more text). Use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` instead.

Comment: @Socowi in general I agree; in practice here I was trying to make sure the behavior would be consistent for people who might have installed later versions of bash onto macos from homebrew or other sources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, in more "recent" version of bash this is no longer a problem.  For versions 4.3 and below we find the following:

First of all, whether or not the assignment is in a sourced script plays no role; the function makes a difference. However, the function alone also doesn't cause your problem. Only the combination of function + `export` causes the array to be local.

If you remove the `export` in front of the assignment, everything works fine. In your example you don't have to export the variables anyway. Actually, there is no way to export an array as arrays are not specified in posix.

If you want to create a global variable and also export it then use `declare -xg` instead of `export`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function sourcefile(){
  source /tmp/srcfile
  echo "Sourced array in func: ${sourcedarray[*]}"
  echo "Sourced scalar in func: ${sourcedscalar}"
}

globalarray=([0]="xyzzy" [1]="kaboom")
globalscalar="argle"

cat >/tmp/srcfile <<EOF
declare -xg sourcedscalar="bargle"
# whether or not you use `-x` makes no difference for the environment
declare -xga sourcedarray=([0]="foo" [1]="bar")
EOF

sourcefile

echo "Global array: ${globalarray[*]}"
echo "Global scalar: ${globalscalar}"
echo "Sourced array: ${sourcedarray[*]}"
echo "Sourced scalar: ${sourcedscalar}"
```

Comment: And here's [the changelog entry](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES?h=bash-4.4#n252): bash-4.4-beta -> bash-4.4-rc1: "p.  Fixed a bug that caused 'readonly' and 'export' to create local array variables when used within shell functions."

Comment: OP here: I believe we have a winner.  Removing the 'export' keywords from /tmp/srcfile appears to solve the problem!  Worth noting that `declare -g` actually doesn't help my case: the `-g` option only appeared in bash 4, and macos still ships with, lord help us, 3.2.57.